# SSH public Key Authentification still ask for Password with public key

Tags: ssh, unix

I have two servers, one is local and one is on the web. I want to synchronize with a crontab job (`crontab -e`) every day at 4:00 AM between two folders on those servers. I'd like to use Unison with a RSA generated key for this. I have generated the public key in the local server and copied it to the second server with the command `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server`.

When I test the key I am asked about password authentication. I want to avoid this and instead use the public key SSH which I have already generated. So the synchronization between both folders doesn't ask for a password.

Another question is, can I do this synchronization if in the first server I use a different user as the second user?

To install Unison and generate the key I have used this

- https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Unison/
- https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Comment: Do you have SSH configured to use/accept public key authentication? Did you password protect the key?

Comment: In the same veign as Seth asks - are you referring to requiring your password or the keys passphrase - and does the key have a passphrase?

Comment: On my /etc/ssh/sshd_config i have `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and i have not set a password/passphrase to secure my RSA Key.    When i give this syntax: ssh -v -i /home/administrator/.ssh/webserver_rsa.pub serveruser@192.168.....   i recive this `
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/administrator/.ssh/webserver_rsa.pub': 
debug1: Next authentication method: password`

Comment: Post the debug log from your `ssh -vvv remoteserver`.

Comment: debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrator/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/administrator/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

Now i recive this:    debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method`